# Why WebSocket cannot connect on Firefox, IE, Edge?

Tags: qt, websocket

I have a test websocket server written in c++ with qt. It listens on 2 ports, one for ws and another one for wss. Whenever i try to test connection to ws it usually works (except on Win10 with IE11 and Edge). However, the wss connection cannot be opened from Firefox, IE11 nor Edge. It works just fine with Chrome and Opera. It even (sometimes) works with IE11 on Win 8.1 and Firefox. But it never works with IE11 or Edge on Windows 10. It also doesn't work on Ubuntu with Firefox. I am getting a response like: {"trusted":"true"}. In the WebSocket monitor i see "Disconnected code 1006".
What could be the reason for not working on some browsers, and how to find the exact cause? I have a valid ssl certificate on the server where i am testing. Furthermore, if i try the echo test at https://www.websocket.org/echo.html it works as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that you are missing chain certificates. Chrome (and Opera) try to work around this problem in various ways, other browsers don't. Try [SSLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look out for incomplete chain.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Qt bug and can be fixed by patching Qt: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57665